# element following emty inline-block div has strange padding at top

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering myself, why an empty div, that has the `display:inline-block` style behaves differently from a div that cointains text. It somehow seems to add some top-padding to following elements, that cannot be removed.

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <div class="a">A</div><div class="b">B</div>
</p>
<p>
    <div class="a"></div><div class="b">B</div>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.a {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
}
.b {
    background-color:orange;
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:12px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

**[There's also a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esacnpLc/1/)**

Can someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inline elements are `vertical-align: baseline` by default. The baseline is affected by the text.

Change to `vertical-align: top / middle / bottom`

[From the MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

> baseline
>
> Aligns the baseline of the element with the baseline of its parent. The baseline of some replaced elements, like `<textarea>` is not specified by the HTML specification, meaning that their behavior with this keyword may change from one browser to the other.

### Your new example

```css
.a {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.b {
  background-color: orange;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
br {
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<br />
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b">B</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, even if i still don't understand what the baseline is :D Thx!

Comment: @VanCoding - [This might help](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/) :) it applies to all inline elements.

Comment: Oh, well I thought about it the wrong way around. Thanks :)